# UITableViewCell separator is not showing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

When I run app that time cell separator is not showing ,,,and when I scrolling that time cell separator is showing and when leave it ideal again cell separator is not showing .
Please help me ???

Comment: Please post a screenshot or some code

Comment: Which version of OS are you using and are you using simulator or real device?
There is some bug in simulator for iOS 9 and above where the separator lines are not visible and when the table view is scrolled they become visible

Comment: If you are test it on simulator then please press command + 1 or command + 2 and then check it.

Comment: Check your dimensions your storyboard and height margins may be different

Comment: Yes change resolution with command + 1 or Command + 2, you will get seprator.

Comment: I am testing on  simulator

Comment: I am using OS 10.11 @Arun

Comment: I asked about the version of simulator you are using

Comment: I using Xcode 7.2 @Arun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test on real device you will see separator always. if you want to see it on Simulator, then make simulator size to 100% then see table. Separator will always be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Check your app in real device and check see separator is show or not. Sometime's separator not show in simulator. If in device not show separator to check your tableview following property.

Set your TableView Property

[image]

Otherwise try this code

```
//Set show separator
[objTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];

//Set separator color
objTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```